# VBA excel compile error : Expected Sub,Function, or property

Tags: vba

I am trying to run Rungenkutta differential problem in excel VBA
 program is as follows

```
Sub Rungenkutta()


Dim Noofitrations As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Noofitrations = Cells(2, 10)
n = Cells(3, 10)
h = Cells(3, 4)
col = 8
x0 = Cells(col, 9)
y0 = Cells(col, 10)

For i = 1 To Noofitrations

 Cells(7, 3) = x0
 Cells(7, 4) = y0
 xn = x0 + h
 yn = y0 + Cells(18, 3)

 ii i Mod n
 If ii = 0 Then
    col = col + 1
    Cells(col, 9) = xn
    Cells(col, 10) = yn
 End If
 x0 = xn
 y0 = yn

Next


End Sub
```

but while running I am getting "VBA excel compile error : Expected Sub,Function, or property"

I am not understanding what shall i do to run the program

Comment: Does it point to a line of your code when it fails?

Comment: `ii i Mod n` isn't legal VBA - should this be `ii = i Mod n` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the Mod operator. VBA doesn't recognize the syntax you provided.

Here is some documentation for the Mod operator - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx

Th Mod operator is a binary operator and requires one left and one right argument.

You need to change

```
ii i Mod n
```

to

```
ii = i Mod n
```

Here is the revised example you provided.

```
Sub Rungenkutta()


Dim Noofitrations As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Noofitrations = Cells(2, 10)
n = Cells(3, 10)
h = Cells(3, 4)
col = 8
x0 = Cells(col, 9)
y0 = Cells(col, 10)

For i = 1 To Noofitrations

Cells(7, 3) = x0
Cells(7, 4) = y0
xn = x0 + h
yn = y0 + Cells(18, 3)

ii = i Mod n
If ii = 0 Then
   col = col + 1
   Cells(col, 9) = xn
   Cells(col, 10) = yn
End If
x0 = xn
y0 = yn

Next


End Sub
```